# Solution to this radical equation?

Tags: radicals

Is $-1$ a solution to $\sqrt{4x+5}=x$ ? 
 Why or why not?

Comment: No, because $\sqrt{4x+5} \geq 0$.

Comment: Sure it is, but make sure to mention that you don't restrict yourself to the principal branch of the square root or a lot of people will get mad.

Comment: At the same time, it teaches you that, when you square both sides of the equation (obtaining $4x+5=x^2$), you don't end up with an equivalent equation. What you get may have solutions that the original equation did not have. Precisely, you get $-1$ and $5$, but only $5$ is the solution of the original equation.

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking for real solutions, there is one. Indeed,

\begin{align*}
\sqrt{4x+5} = x \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
4x + 5 = x^{2}\\
x \geq 0
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
x^{2} - 4x  - 5 = 0\\
x \geq 0
\end{cases} \Longleftrightarrow
\begin{cases}
(x-2)^{2} - 9 = 0\\
x\geq 0
\end{cases}
\end{align*}

Therefore the solution set is $S = \{5\}$, since the other root is negative.

Comment: I think there is a small sign problem in your third step, it should be -5

Comment: Oh, thanks for the comment. I'll edit it.

Answer (score 0):

$$\sqrt{4x+5}=x$$

$=(\sqrt{4x+5})^2=x^2$

$=4x+5=x^2$

$0=x^2-4x-5$

$0=(x-5)(x+1)$

So $x=5$ is a solution (real). $x=-1$ is not solution since our range is greater than zero. By squaring both sides, we made negative solutions possible so we had to reject them at the end.